# Converting an Entire Column of a data set from excel Using R (Character to Numeric)

Tags: r

Converting an Entire Column of a data set from excel Using R
What I need to do is convert an entire column of Characters to Numeric so could use cluster analysis on the data

```
e <- d %>% select(c(15, 16, 18, 20))
sapply(e, class)
g
g <- as.numeric(as.character(e))
sapply(g, class)
g
summary(g)
```

Comment: Do you want to convert all the columns of `e` to numeric? `e[] <- lapply(e, as.numeric)`

Comment: @RonakShah yes Sir, but it says here that :  In lapply(e, as.numeric) : NAs introduced by coercion
2: In lapply(e, as.numeric) : NAs introduced by coercion